# How to allow single quote with esc_html__() without sprintf()

Tags: html, localization, escaping

Because of security reasons we are of course required to use [esc_html__()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html__/) for WP development. This is annoying because if you'd want to pass a single quote into your strings, you'd have to use [sprintf()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to make it work. Otherwise you just get `&#039;` printed out, instead of a `'`.

Without using [sprintf()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
esc_html__( 'Wasn\'t your favorite color red?', 'domain' );
// Output: Wasn&#039;t your favorite color red?
esc_html__( 'Provided reason isn\'t selected', 'domain' );
// Output: Provided reason isn&#039;t selected
```

With the use of [sprintf()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) I can get single quotes to work (of course).

```
sprintf( esc_html__( 'Wasn%st your favorite color red?', 'domain' ), '\'' );
// Output: Wasn't your favorite color red?
sprintf( esc_html__( 'Provided reason isn%st selected', 'domain' ), '\'' );
// Output: Provided reason isn't selected
```

I'd like to know if there is a different way to achieve the same output. I am afraid there is none, but I thought why not give it a shot, who knows.

Comment: That is exactly how it is supposed to work. The `esc_html` is going to escape the single quotes to `&#039;`, and in HTML it will show it correctly. What you are doing is escaping the HTML first, without single quotes, and then the sprintf replaces the `$s` for the `\'`, so you are not preparing that single quote to be printed in HTML

Comment: Yes I know it is supposed to do that. The problem was that it wasn't displaying correctly in HTML, but this was apparently due to the fact that I parsed it into JS via `wp_localize_script()`. And then into the DOM, which causes it to not be converted back into a straight quote. A way around it is to use smart/curly quote. As explained in the Accepted Answer. Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, a different way to output you say?

```php
<?php if ( 'en_US' === get_locale() ) : ?>
    Wasn't your favorite color red?
<?php endif; ?>
```

:laughing:

But seriously, I mean anything can be done if you *want* to do it.  If you look at `esc_html__` - you will see that it's just calling `esc_html`, which is filterable after the safe text has been determined by `_wp_specialchars`.  Looking at `_wp_specialchars` you can see that it's simply doing a string replace on single quotes to the encoded entity.  If you want to undo what it has done, just do the inverse logic to replace the entity with a single quote.  Something like this would work to achieve what you want:

```php
add_filter( 'esc_html', function( $safe_text ) {
    return str_replace( '&#039;', "'", $safe_text );
}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

The real question is ***should you do it?***  Some people often refer to `'` and `"` as dumb quotes.  Ideally these should be used in code, whereas `‘` `’` `“` and `”` are sometimes referred to as smart quotes, fancy quotes, or typographic quotes.  These are commonly thought as being displayable quotes, or quotes that belong to your content.  They are meant to look prettier, and more accurately display the opening and closing of quoted text you want to display to a user/visitor.  As a general rule of thumb, if you're displaying the text for someone to read - it's usually better to use smart quotes - which in part is why `_wp_special_chars` does that conversion.  This is also done in the `wptexturize` filter throughout WordPress for displayed content - things like content, comments, nav_menu titles, link_name, term_description, bloginfo values, and widget_titles to name just a few places.

Obviously there isn't a huge amount of risk involved by using dumb quotes for HTML output - but there are some scenarios where it could cause an issue if something was poorly written/overlooked.  By filtering that value, you would need to be more responsible than the snippet I provided, and do something to ensure you're only filtering values that you are adding via plugin/theme code to ensure that you don't cause open vectors from someone else's code. Ideally you'd want to check that the text being filtered belongs to your textdomain before tampering.  This is another reason why it's not a good idea to change the filtered value here as it's extremely uncommon to use this filter - and VERY common for plugins and themes to have code that is ran through it.

So should you do it?  **No**, but if you have an absolutely necessary need for this behavior - sure there's ways to make it happen, even your example shows a way to annoyingly work around it.  I've even seen people convert it back via JS when the page is loaded, which seems a bit drastic.  In modern times though, it's not being done so much for the security aspect, but more for the display value it provides to people reading content.  Just don't be silly and think that allowing it in user input forms, or doing the same technique `esc_attr` is a good idea though.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I just have to use the smart/curly quotes in my situation. I am using `wp_localize_script()` and then storing the strings that are required to be translated. I noticed that the straight quote actually displays correctly when I call `esc_html__()` directly in my HTML. So basically the javascript has access to the string, which contains `&#039;` then I put it into the DOM and it stays like regular text. So it is kind of a combination of using the above two functions I guess. I will stick to the smart/curly quotes. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

The [source code for `esc_html()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html/) uses `$safe_text = _wp_specialchars($safe_text, ENT_QUOTES);` to handle quotes. The description for the second parameter of the `_wp_specialchars()` function states:

> Converts double quotes if set to ENT_COMPAT, both single and double if set to ENT_QUOTES or none if set to ENT_NOQUOTES. Converts single and double quotes, as well as converting HTML named entities (that are not also XML named entities) to their code points if set to ENT_XML1.

With that said, you can hook into the filter to change the quote type like this:

```
/**
 * Filters a string cleaned and escaped for output in HTML.
 *
 * Text passed to esc_html() is stripped of invalid or special characters
 * before output.
 *
 * @param string $safe_text The text after it has been escaped.
 * @param string $text The text prior to being escaped.
 *
 * @return string The text after it has been escaped.
 */
function custom_esc_html($safe_text, $text) {
    $safe_text = wp_check_invalid_utf8($text);
    return _wp_specialchars($safe_text, ENT_COMPAT); // Only convert double quotes
}
add_filter('esc_html', 'custom_esc_html', 20, 2);
```